# How to have VS Code only create some of the component files by default?

Tags: aura, vs-code

In VS Code, when I create a an Aura Component, it creates the full Aura Component Bundle with all the files. Is there a way to limit what it creates? Ideally, limit it to the helper, controller, cmp, and cmp.xml)?  The reason is that 9 times out of 10 I don't use the other files and it creates noise in my repo.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The creation of these files are controlled by the underlying functions (e.g. force:lightning:component:create for LWC and Aura components). These commands always output all the files they're designed to, and there's no documented way to prevent these files from being created. Some alternative options follow.

- You can commit just the files you want to keep and then `git clean --force` to delete anything left over.
- You can just manually delete the files.
- You could write a sfdx extension to create just files that you want (e.g. adding a command that accepts optional flags).

Ultimately, while it is annoying, it doesn't take many clicks to delete the files you don't need.